# Conditional Drag & Drop of images

Tags: java, android, image, if-statement, drag-and-drop

As I am new to this I will ask a question that maybe for many of you is very simple, but me, I have followed tutorials all day in order to understand how this works, but unfortunately I wasn't that lucky.

I'm building an children app where they have to drag an image of an animal over the corresponding shadow. Therefore in the example below they would have to drag the image of the cow over the shadow of the cow.

If they drag it over a wrong image there will be a sound notice saying so, if they drag it over the correct image the image will replace the shadow and there will e a confirmation sound.

Up till now I managed to code the part where I drag the cow image over any of the shadows and replaces them. I would like to replace only when it's the correct one.

I will add below my code and hopefully someone will be able to help me!

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/animals_types"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:id="@+id/gamesCategory"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/games_cow"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:id="@+id/text_cow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gamesCategory"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/games_cow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text_cow"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/games_cow_item" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/games_cow_shadow"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/games_cow_item"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/games_cow_shadow"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/games_pig_shadow"
    android:maxHeight="130dp"
    android:maxWidth="130dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/games_cow_item"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/games_pig_shadow"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/games_horse_shadow"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/games_cow_shadow"
    android:id="@+id/games_horse_shadow"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/games_horse_shadow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Java:

```
 package com.gadgetcatch.firstwords;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 2/1/2016.
 */
public class GamesAnimals extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView option, choice1, choice2, choice3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.games_animals);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        //View to drag

        option = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.games_cow_item);

        //Views to drop unto

        choice1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.games_cow_shadow);
        choice2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.games_pig_shadow);
        choice3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.games_horse_shadow);

        //set touch listener

        option.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

        //set drag listeners

        choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        choice2.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());
        choice3.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener());


    }

    private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener{
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                //setup drag
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

                //start dragging the item touched
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


    private class ChoiceDragListener implements View.OnDragListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            //handle drag events
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    //no action necessary
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    //no action necessary
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    //no action necessary
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view - asta de deasupra
                    //handle the dragged view being dropped over a target view -asta de jos
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    //view dragged item is being dropped on
                    ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;
                    //view being dragged and dropped
                    ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;
                    //update the image in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
                    dropTarget.setImageDrawable(dropped.getDrawable());

                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    //no action necessary
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an image of the .xml in case I have't explained myself good enough.

Thanks in advance for any advice!
[cow_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d50BA.jpg)

Comment: you have done a great job sir, very great. and you are good at what you do.  thats btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it nearly done :) you just need to check if the image is the correct one. From your code I see all that logic is missing. There are a million ways to do this, but I'd suggest you to use the `TAG` property of the views to store information about each image.

A **Tag** is something you can store on any view. It can be a `String`, a number, whatever. For clarity let's use a `String`. **We'll set the same TAG to matching images / shadows:**

- Image COW SHADOW will have the tag "COW", same as Image COW
- Image PIG SHADOW will have the tag "PIG", same as Image PIG.
- Image HORSE SHADOW will have the tag "HORSE", same as Image Horse.

Then in your case ACTION_DROP, you'll check that both tags of the shadow and the dropped image are the same, like this:

```
   .
   .
   .
   case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
       .
       .
       .
       // view dragged item is being dropped on
       ImageView dropTarget = (ImageView) v;
       // view being dragged and dropped
       ImageView dropped = (ImageView) view;

       String tagDropTarget = (String)dropTarget.getTag(),
              tagDroppedImage = (String)dropped.getTag();

       if ((tagDropTarget != null) && (tagDropTarget.equals (tagDroppedImage)) {

            // yippie! correct!!
            // update the image in the target view to reflect the data being dropped

            dropTarget.setImageDrawable(dropped.getDrawable());
        } else {
            // oppps, wrong!!!!
            .
            .
        }
        break;
```

And now we need to set the tags in the XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:tag="COW"
    .
    .
    android:src="@drawable/games_cow"
    android:id="@+id/games_cow_item" />

<ImageView
    android:tag="COW"
    .
    .
    android:src="@drawable/games_cow_shadow"
    android:id="@+id/games_cow_shadow"/>

<ImageView
    android:tag="PIG"
    .
    .
    android:src="@drawable/games_pig_shadow"
    android:id="@+id/games_pig_shadow"/>

<ImageView
    android:tag="HORSE"
    .
    .
    android:src="@drawable/games_horse_shadow"
    android:id="@+id/games_horse_shadow"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like a charm:-) I saw your profile, and you are not just anybody when it comes to programming:-) Can I bother you with an advice also...I am at the beginning with Android Development and the problems that I have is with Java syntax. What book would you recommend or what online training for beginners would you recommend so I could understand this better. I am currently preparing to begin https://www.udacity.com/courses/cs046 but I am afraid that I do not have yet the requested knowledge to understand it properly. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I have mentioned that class as I already did from them the  Android Development for Beginners course and the How to Create <Anything> in Android course. After doing the Java one I would like to go for their Nanodegree payed program for the Google certification.

Comment: hmm the first of them says that no previous computing experience is needed, just launched it and seems pretty basic. Go for it then the google's course seems a logical step. But don't underestimate yourself, the only key is practice over and over again! Do stuff like that game! Don't focus on getting everything working but in understanding what's going on. Maybe you can practice Java alone before, mind that an Android app has a lot of stuff going on that may well overwhelm you at the beginning.

Comment: That's my problem:-) I am overwhelmed already as I am doing a lot of things that I do not completely understand. Java is my week point. I need to understand more and that's why I'm going for that course. My way of doing it is to make it work first and after, try to understand why did I do it like that:-) In fact if I could pour all this info in my head without reading the documentation...that would be great:-)Thanks for your time!